# How to extract an web page archive and display that on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm downloading the archive from ardaka.com/koa.zip. After downloading I need to extract it but I cannot. Which module that need to use? I tried to use Simple Unzipper and SSZipArchive, but it didn't helped. My second question is how to display the html content that I extracted? You can see the code for webView that I used but I cannot access the html file which is located(I think I can extract it in documents) in Documents folder. Maybe I can use other archive formats if there is useful extractor.

Web View Code:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(documentsPath.index, withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "koa") //It's not working
let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
webView.loadRequest(myRequest);
```